# What is the maximum speed a Blackbird (wind-powered vehicle) can achieve?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, propulsion

Can someone drive/calculate the maximum speed which can be achieved by a Blackbird (wind-powered vehicle, link below) when going downwind?

Suppose mass of the vehicle is $m$, wind speed relative to the ground $w$ (horizontal) ,vehicle speed relative to the ground $v$, the area of the vehicle perpendicular to the wind $A$, maximum static friction coefficient on the ground $k$.

If I missed some info you can add more parameters.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackbird_(wind-powered_vehicle)

Comment: It is not that simple, a physics college professor already lost 10K

Comment: This is a tricky question, but a crude analysis is perfectly reasonable at a high school level. See pp. 10 - 12 of the [USAPhO 2013 solutions](https://www.aapt.org/physicsteam/2019/upload/USAPhO-2013-Solutions.pdf).

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/649726/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @DanDan0101 I didn't read it yet, but thanks!

Comment: @Wolphramjonny I've always doubted that story - where would a college professor get 10K ? :-)